# is it possible to make a auto burn function for every transaction?

Tags: solidity, burn

I need help from ‍solidity language experts,
Is it possible to make a function of smart contract where 1% buy fee equivalent of the token will be burned automatically from the total supply on every transaction?
if possible then reply with function....